# What should I do after my iPhone was stolen?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

My iPhone was stolen, what can I do to protect my data and get the phone back?

Comment: I'm not sure if I do follow, please exuse me I'm really nervous and shaky as I type all this. So what should I do? I'm currently using my brother's tablet  (Samsung) to try find it. Should I wait for the person to switch it on again? 

by the way my bundles were switched off the last time I had my phone, is there a possible way of finding it even if my data is switched off?

Comment: You can lock/erase/trace your phone with [Find My Phone](http://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html)  The other thing I would have hoped you have done is report it stolen.

Comment: I'm from the police station and I've been asked to black list the phone in order to get some address which requires two numbers that they need. Now I have a question how will I find it if I black list my phone?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to hear that, but if you have your iPhone setup with iCloud then most likely you have *Find my iPhone* setup and by following [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mmfc0f0165&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=MobileMe133314) you'll be able to place your phone in Lost Mode and that person won't be able to view any of your content and if you have iOS version 7.0 (which you do, as the iPhone 5s shipped with iOS 7) or later then the phone will have an [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365) meaning that this person could never activate this iPhone even if they place the device into DFU mode.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have Find My iPhone enabled, you can go to iCloud.com and lock the device and locate it on a map. If the phone is not on when you find it, it will alert you when it is turned on and located. Once you know where it is, you can get it or have the police get it, depending on the situation.

Besides that, I'd recommend calling Apple at 1-800-MYAPPLE and seeing if they can help you disassociate it from your Apple account, and you can report it to your cell carrier so the phone will be disabled permanently.

Comment: Alright thank you. I'll log in on my iclould and see what happens. Thank you Pinchus Gelbman and Kal-al